# Understand the nslookup output.

Tags: osx, nslookup

nslookup returns the following output on mac:

```
www.yahoo.com -> 46.228.47.115, 46.228.47.114, 2a00:1288:110:2::4001
```

As I understand following IPs in DNS map to www.yahoo.com:

```
www.yahoo.com -> 46.228.47.115
www.yahoo.com -> 46.228.47.114
```

But what is:

```
2a00:1288:110:2::4001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That represents IPv6,

In short form it is, `2a00:1288:110:2::4001`, which represents

```
2a00:1288:0110:0002:0000:0000:0000:4001
```

in long form.